# Using Atmel Studio 7 to program Arduino Uno

Tags: arduino, atmega, atmega328p, atmel-studio

**I will like to use AS7 IDE to program the Arduino board, for start Im using Arduino UNO with  ATMEGA328P-PU chip. Im using Windows 10 professional**

First I used the Arduino IDE in  order to run/confirm this simple program that blinks the orange LED (pin 13) in a Fibonacci pattern up to Fib 100. The program uploads & works fine using Arduino IDE.

**Arduino code:**

```
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  pinMode(13,OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
 int i = 0; 
 int n =100; 
 int t1 = 0; 
 int t2 = 1; 
 int numberOnOff; 
 for ( i = 1; i<=n; i++)
 {
  numberOnOff = t1 + t2; 
  t1 = t2; 
  t2 = numberOnOff; 
  delay(3000);
  int counter = 0; 
  while (counter <  numberOnOff)
  {
    onOff(); 
    counter++; 
  }
 }

}


void onOff()
{
 digitalWrite(13,HIGH);
 delay(1000);
 digitalWrite(13,LOW);
 delay(1000);
}
```

**Then I migrated to AS7 IDE & used this video tutorial :** https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zEbSQaQJvHI

step 1) I copied the Arduino upload command & formatted it:

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe

-C"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM6 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(TargetName).hex":i
```

step 2) I navigated to AS7 "Tools" menu, then "External Tools", then created a build tool titled using copied paths from step 1 "Arduino_via_bootloader":

I set the value of Command =

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\bin\avrdude.exe
```

And the value of Arguments =

```
 -C"C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\ArduinoLLC.ArduinoIDE_1.8.15.0_x86__mdqgnx93n4wtt\hardware\tools\avr\etc\avrdude.conf" -v -patmega328p -carduino -PCOM6 -b115200 -D -Uflash:w:"$(ProjectDir)Debug\$(TargetName).hex":i
```

[image]

Clicked OK & apply.

**step 3) Then I modified my C code (main.c) :**

```
/*
 * Arduino2.c
 *
 * Created: 11/6/2018 5:48:19 PM
 * Author : cyber101
 */ 

#define F_CPU 16000000
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <util/delay.h>

void loop();
void onOff();

int main(void)
{
    /* Replace with your application code */
    while (1) 
    {
        loop();
    }
}



void loop() {
    // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    int i = 0;
    int n =100;
    int t1 = 0;
    int t2 = 1;
    int numberOnOff;
    for ( i = 1; i<=n; i++)
    {
        numberOnOff = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = numberOnOff*3;
        _delay_ms(3000);
        int counter = 0;
        while (counter <  numberOnOff)
        {
            onOff();
            counter++;
        }
    }

}


void onOff()
{
    /* Insert application code here, after the board has been initialized. */
    PORTB |= 0B00100000;
    _delay_ms(1000);
    PORTB &= 0B11011111;
    _delay_ms(1000);
}
```

step 4) I Build the project & got  success:

```
    Done executing task "RunCompilerTask".
    Using "RunOutputFileVerifyTask" task from assembly "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Extensions\Application\AvrGCC.dll".
    Task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask"
                Program Memory Usage    :   308 bytes   0.9 % Full
                Data Memory Usage       :   0 bytes   0.0 % Full
    Done executing task "RunOutputFileVerifyTask".
Done building target "CoreBuild" in project "Arduino2.cproj".
Target "PostBuildEvent" skipped, due to false condition; ('$(PostBuildEvent)' != '') was evaluated as ('' != '').
Target "Build" in file "C:\Program Files (x86)\Atmel\Studio\7.0\Vs\Avr.common.targets" from project "c:\users\anaim\Documents\Atmel Studio\7.0\Arduino2\Arduino2\Arduino2.cproj" (entry point):
Done building target "Build" in project "Arduino2.cproj".
Done building project "Arduino2.cproj".

Build succeeded.
========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

**step 5) Finally, I navigated  to the "Tools" menu & selected my custom build "Arduino_via_bootloader". However nothing happens, AS7 Output console is empty to messages, no errors, no feedback? And the board is not blinking. 
How can fix this build process???**

Thanks a million.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I successfully use a different approach for getting AtmelStudio to program a device with a bootloader, and that is to use the "Custom Programming Tool".

In the "Solution Explorer" window, right-click on your project and select "Properties". This should open a tab with various settings like Build, Toolchain, etc. On this tab you will find a section called "Tool" as pictured below.

[image: Tool Selection]

There is a drop-down menu on the Tool section called "Selected debugger/programmer", and from this you can select "Custom Programming Tool" as the option.

[image: Select Programmer Dropdown]

This should bring up a text filed called "Custom programming tool -> Command:", in which you can enter a command/program to be run.

[image: Custom Programmer Command]

Enter the following command:

```
"<path\to>\avrdudeStdout.bat" "<path\to\avrdude>\bin\avrdude.exe" "<path\to\avrdude>\etc\avrdude.conf" "COM6" "arduino" "115200" "$(OutputDirectory)\$(OutputFileName).hex" $(avrdevice)
```

You should change the command to suit your needs. The following should be changed:

- `"<path\to>\avrdudeStdout.bat"` - the location of the batch file explained later in this answer
- `"<path\to\avrdude>\bin\avrdude.exe"` - the location of your avrdude.exe
- `"<path\to\avrdude>\etc\avrdude.conf"` - the location of your avrdude.conf
- `"COM6"` - which COM port you are using
- `"arduino"` - which programmer you are using (e.g. "arduino" for Arduino bootloader
- `"115200"` - which baud rate to use

Don't change anything else, especially things in `$()` - these are automatically calculated by AtmelStudio!

Finally, you will need to save the following into a file called `avrdudeStdout.bat`, which you can either put in your AS7 project directory, or with the avrdude.exe file.

```
@echo off

set avrdude=%~1
set conf=%~2
set port=%~3
set prog=%~4
set baud=%~5
set hexfile=%~6
set device=%~7

echo Running AVRDude With Command:
echo "%avrdude%" -C"%conf%" -p%device% -c%prog% -b%baud% -D -v -Uflash:w:"%hexfile%":i -P%port% 2>&1

"%avrdude%" -C"%conf%" -p%device% -c%prog% -b%baud% -D -v -Uflash:w:"%hexfile%":i -P%port% 2>&1
```

The batch file is necessary to stop AS7 from saying there was a programming error ([see here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/318211/atmel-studio-7-custom-build-tool-output) if you want more details as to why).

---

Once the custom programming tool is set up, programming your Arduino is a simple case of pressing the green "Play" button on the main toolbar (or from the menu, select "Debug->Start Without Debugging (Ctrl+Alt+F5)".

Answer (score 1):

Check the "avrdude.exe" and "avrdude.conf" location installation, which I used the Microsoft Store to install the Arduino IDE. When executing the "avrdude.exe" on the command line, there is an "Access Denied" error, that is the reason why there is no Output on the Atmel Studio.

The solution I did was to copy the "avrdude.exe" and "avrdude.conf" to another folder, say on the "Atmel Studio" installation folder. Change then the Command and Arguments on the "External Tools" to use the copied avr files.